# React Native Error message when using FireBase on EXPO iOS emulator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a login for an app. It works fine on android and web. When I try it on my iOS device using Expo Go, I get the error message below. Here is my login code:

```
    const handleLogin = () => {
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
.then((userCredential) => {
const user = userCredential.user;
console.log('logged in')
  }).catch((error) => {
    alert(error)
  });
```

I have looked everywhere, but I cant seem to find a fix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell which firebase version are you using?

Comment: I am using te latest version. Testing on my iPhone 13 pro.

Comment: can you check this [doc] [https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#create_a_reference]  is it helpful?